# Not able to display checkboxes for ListViewItems in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I want to display checkboxes alongside text in ListView. I have multiple ListViews in my WPF window, hence I want to specify this behavior as a style in resources. But the checkboxes are not displayed, only the text is. So please, find below my code and suggest edits.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListView"  x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" Content=""></CheckBox>
                        <Separator Width="5"></Separator>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.RowSpan="5" x:Name="listViewDocTypes" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewTemplate}"    >
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide a `Text` or `Width` to the `Checkbox`. Without setting the `Text` property the length will automatically be "0" if you do not specify its `Width`.

```
<CheckBox Content="xyz" Width="1234"/>
```

Comment: Did you try to set the `Orientation` of the `Stack Panel` to `Vertical`?

Comment: The problem was with binding, my bad

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was binding data the wrong way.I was using the following code.

```
 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                        item.Tag = docType;
                        item.Text = docType.Text;
                        listViewDocTypes.Items.Add(item);
```

The correct way to bind is

```
listViewDocTypes.ItemsSource = docTypes;
```